# Packaging shell action files with Oozie, retaining original directory structure

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark, oozie

I have a PySpark application I would like to schedule with Oozie, using the shell action.
My `submit-application.sh` script simply initializes a Python virtualenv (present on all worker nodes) and calls the `application.py` Python application script.

The `application.py` script is a PySpark application that comes with one own local Python module, let's say called `foobar`, which is simply imported and used throughout the code.

So I have a directory structure similar to this:

```
.
├── foobar
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── foobar.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── application.DEV.ini
├── application.PROD.ini
├── application.py
├── requirements.txt
└── submit-application.sh
```

I am trying to use an Oozie workflow to package all script and local module files, but apparently, they are always delivered as flattened, dumped into the **root** directory of the container, regardless any configuration I used. This prevents the Python script from loading the local modules, causing  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foobar'` errors.

Is not there any way to tell Oozie to place file artifacts to a sub-directory?
It seems that the `#` notation is just ignored.

This is my Oozie `workflow.xml` file

```
<workflow-app name="Data-Extraction-WF" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">

    <global>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
    </global>

    <start to="Data-Extraction"/>

    <action name="Data-Extraction">
        <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:1.0">
            <exec>submit-application.sh</exec>

            <file>app/__init__.py#app/__init__.py</file>
            <file>app/config.py#app/config.py</file>
            <file>app/foobar.py#app/foobar.py</file>
            <file>application.DEV.ini#application.DEV.ini</file>
            <file>application.PROD.ini#application.PROD.ini</file>
            <file>application.py#application.py</file>
            <file>submit-application.sh#submit-application.sh</file>

            <capture-output/>
        </shell>

        <ok to="success"/>
        <error to="failure"/>
    </action>


    <kill name="failure">
        <message>Workflow failed, error message: [${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>

    <end name="success"/>

</workflow-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a wrapper script that gets the files from HDFS and
simply using that within the Oozie workflow. In addition of the HDFS location
of the workflow, the step (sub-directory) is passed to this script, which
then downloads the whole directory and executes the run script inside.

```
<workflow-app name="Data-Extraction-WF" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">

    <global>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
    </global>

    <start to="Data-Extraction"/>

    <action name="Data-Extraction">
        <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:1.0">
            <exec>execute_workflow_step.sh</exec>

            <argument>-w</argument>
            <argument>${wf:conf('oozie.wf.application.path')}</argument>
            <argument>-s</argument>
            <argument>data-transformation</argument>

            <file>execute_workflow_step.sh</file>
        </shell>

        <ok to="success"/>
        <error to="failure"/>
    </action>


    <kill name="failure">
        <message>Workflow failed, error message: [${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>

    <end name="success"/>

</workflow-app>
```

This is my `execute_workflow_step.sh` script: it downloads the step directory from the HDFS directory of the workflow and executes its run script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

err_trap() {
    echo "*** FAILED: Error on line $1"
    exit 1
}

trap 'err_trap $LINENO' ERR


usage() { echo "Usage: $0 [-w <workflow HDFS path>] [-s <step-directory>] [-p <step submit script parameters>]" 1>&2; exit 1; }

PARAMETERS=""

while getopts ":w:s:p:" o; do
    case "${o}" in
        w)
            WORKFLOW_PATH=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        s)
            STEP_DIRECTORY=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        p)
            PARAMETERS=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        *)
            usage
            ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

if [ -z "${WORKFLOW_PATH}" ] || [ -z "${STEP_DIRECTORY}" ]; then
    usage
fi

HDFS_BASEDIR=$(dirname "${WORKFLOW_PATH}")

WORKFLOW_STEP_DIRECTORY="${HDFS_BASEDIR}/${STEP_DIRECTORY}"

echo "Getting: ${WORKFLOW_STEP_DIRECTORY}"
hdfs dfs -get "${WORKFLOW_STEP_DIRECTORY}"

STEP_SCRIPT="${STEP_DIRECTORY}/submit-application.sh"

chmod 755 "$STEP_SCRIPT"

echo "Step submit script: ${STEP_SCRIPT}"
echo "Parameters: ${PARAMETERS}"


echo "Invoking: ${STEP_SCRIPT} ${PARAMETERS}"

"${STEP_SCRIPT}" "${PARAMETERS}"
```